# Lightbox e Link, modificar funcionamento

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

Bom dia. Esse lightbox do meio, onde pede login e senha, só aparece depois que o usuário clica naquele link "Acesso Restrito".
Existe algum meio desse lightbox aparecer automaticamente? Já verifiquei exaustivamente que esse funcionamento não foi configurado através de interface visual (plugin, painel de tema ou do wordpress). Teriam alguma sugestão de configuração através de código? (consigo implementar, em alguns casos). Só há interesse em manter ativo um sistema de gerenciamento por trás desse login. O site comercial que aparece atrás será ocultado e substituído por outro, em outro domínio. Agradeço. (WordPress 4.4.14 com o tema Enfold Child). [Link](http://habitareparticipacoes.com.br/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVIDO: o lightbox passou a aparecer automaticamente alterando o arquivo wp-content/themes/enfold-child/js/access.js, substituindo o código:

```js
$loginButton.click(function(e){
 $lightboxWrap.show();
});
```

por:

```js
$loginButton.click(function(e){
 $lightboxWrap.show();
}).trigger('click');
```